# DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'Name'

Tags: c#, data-binding

while i am trying to bind my drop down button "DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'Name'." occurs. help me to overcome this. thanks in advance.

the code am using is

```
var at = _dbConnect.GetData_DataTable("select * from Employee a where a.department = '3' order by Name");
    ddlPerson.DataSource = cat;
    ddlPerson.DataTextField = "Name";
    ddlPerson.DataValueField = "id";
    ddlPerson.DataBind();
    ddlPerson.Items.Add(new ListItem(" MY NAME ", "0"));
    ddlPerson.SelectedValue = "0";
```

Comment: can you breifly describe your problem? 
where you use datarowView?

Comment: i'm not using datarowView . i just simply binding db values to the dropdown list. <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPerson" runat="server" CssClass="form-control select2me" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlPerson_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" ></asp:DropDownList>

Answer (score 0):

Is the database field called "name" rather than "Name"?

Answer (score 0):

```
var at = _dbConnect.GetData_DataTable("select * from Employee a where a.department = '3' order by Name");
ddlPerson.DataSource = **at**;
```

thanks for the answers and suggestions

Comment: datasource is miss spelled ''at" as ''cat''